# Request Body Read Multiple Value on Node Js

Tags: node.js, arrays, json, request, response

i am new in NodeJs development,
i want to ask, surely this is kinda basic, but i dont know how to do it.

i have a task to read request one field that can filled with multiple values,
on json array like this :

```
{ 
  "email" : "first@mail.com" , "second@mail.com", "third@mail.com" 
}
```

how to get each value from that "email" field and processing it to some function ?

i have a query select to get username from one table

```
select username from [dbo].[users] where email=@email (first, second, and third)
```

this is my code for now only that read one value, not multiple :

```
    async getValueFunction(req, res) {
    
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    
            try {
    
                if (req.body.email != "") {
                    const pool = await poolPromise
                    const result = await pool.request()
                        .input('email', sql.VarChar, req.body.email)
                        .query(queries.getUserScoreByEmail)
                        var showUserScore = result.recordset;
                        res.json(showUserScore);
    
                } else if (req.body.email == "") {
                    const pool = await poolPromise
                    const result = await pool.request()
                        .query(queries.getUserScore)
                        var showAllUserScore = result.recordset;
                        res.json(showAllUserScore);
                }
            } catch (error) {
                res.status(500)
                res.send(error.message)
            }
        }
```

how to do the loop (iteration) and collect the result/recordset before send as one response (json) ??

Answer (score 1):

You should update your structure because it is not an key value pair.

What you can do is storing the E-Mail Adresses in an **Array** like this

```
const data ={ 
    "email" : ["first@mail.com" , "second@mail.com", "third@mail.com" ]
}
```

And then you access it with `data.email`

Comment: i still dont get it.., anyway i edited my question, with the code

Comment: Sorry I missunderstood. That is no valid Json, you have to do key value pairs. But you can do an Array of E-Mail Addresses